# Hadoop FileAlreadyExistsException: Output directory hdfs://<namenode public dns>:9000/input already exists

Tags: java, hadoop, amazon-ec2, jar, mapreduce

I have Hadoop setup in fully distributed mode with one master and 3 slaves. I am trying to execute a jar file named Tasks.jar which is taking arg[0] as input directory and arg[1] as output directory.

In my Hadoop environment, I have the input files in /input directory and there is no /output directory.

I checked the above by using the `hadoop fs -ls /` command

Now, when I try to execute my jar file by using the below command:

```
hadoop jar Tasks.jar ProgrammingAssigment/Tasks /input /output'
```

I get the below exception:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-5-213:~$ hadoop jar Tasks.jar ProgrammingAssignment/Tasks /input /output
16/10/14 02:26:23 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at ec2-52-55-2-64.compute-1.amazonaws.com/172.31.5.213:8032
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileAlreadyExistsException: Output directory hdfs://ec2-52-55-2-64.compute-1.amazonaws.com:9000/input already exists
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat.checkOutputSpecs(FileOutputFormat.java:146)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.checkSpecs(JobSubmitter.java:266)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:139)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1290)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1287)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1287)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:1308)
    at ProgrammingAssignment.Tasks.main(Tasks.java:96)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
```

Comment: show us the main method of Tasks.jar

Answer (score 0):

The stacktrace showing like `hdfs://ec2-52-55-2-64.compute-1.amazonaws.com:9000/input`, in your code output directory mentioned as `/input`,so the above exception occurred. you may need to change the output directory or change the input directory name in hdfs.

Comment: I tried changing the name and I am getting the same error

Comment: Change the output directory in you jar file.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure that /input was passed as your input directory but not output directory. Through the exception

org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat.checkOutputSpecs

/input was considered as your output direcotry.